# Insert record into Multiple table from single excel sheet using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an Excel sheet (input) where it hold customer and address information in one sheet. I wanted to transfer to two different table with reference of CustomerID .

Example:
Excel sheet - CustomerName,First Name, Last Name, Phone,Job Type,Designation ,Address,Zipcode

Need to transfer to below tables

SQL =
Table 1 Customer - CustomerId, First Name,Last Name , Phone ,Job Type,Designation 
Table 2 Address  - AddressId ,CustomerId , Address , Zipcode

I can able to transfer the information independently using SSIS without any relation between two tables.  but how to get the customerId from customer table insert into address table at the time of package execution.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do data clean up from an Excel document with SSIS is possible if the data is EXTREAMLY clean.

My experience is you will have better luck creating the customerID in the excel doc and making sure everything is clean. Exporting it as CSV, and importing the CSV file.

I know this might not be the way you were hoping to do it, but I am sure this will be faster.

Good Luck

BD Softley